# Dropbox stopped syncing automatically

Tags: 20.04, sync, dropbox

I am using Dropbox to sync my files on Ubuntu 20.04.6. Everything was working fine until about a week or so: my files are not synced anymore. If I pause syncing using the system icon at the top of the screen and press resume syncing again, then it starts syncing files properly, but any changes made after that are not synced anymore, and I have to pause/resume again in order to sync my files.

I have run the `dropbox update` command and the output of `dropbox version` and `dropbox status` are:

```
$ dropbox version
Dropbox daemon version: 187.4.5691
Dropbox command-line interface version: 2020.03.04
$ dropbox status
Up to date
```

Why does this happen?